# cakephp 2 application cookbook edit not working

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm following the cakephp 2 application cookbook in chapter 1 page 19
or here:
http://www.cakedc.com/cakephp-tutorials/adding-and-editing-records

I have checked my code a few times and can't find the error that is preventing me from updating a record

If I bake the products database I can do all of the crud operations
My add is working correctly, so the form element should be working correctly

Inside my ProductsController edit function it is not getting post for some reason

```
        if($this->Product->save($this->request->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Product updated'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
```

ProductsController.php in /cakephp/app/Controller

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class ProductsController extends AppController {
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
public $components = array('Session', 'Paginator');
Public $paginate = array('limit' => 10);

public function index() {
    $this->Product->recursive = -1;
    $this->set('products', $this->paginate());
}

public function view($id) {
    if (!($product = $this->Product->findById($id))) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Product not found'));
    }
    $this->set(compact ('product'));
}

public function add() {
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        $this->Product->create();
        if($this->Product->save($this->request->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('New product created'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Could not create product'));
    }
}

public function edit($id){
    $product = $this->Product->findById($id);
    if(!$product){
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Product not found'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post')){
        $this->Product->id = $id;
        if($this->Product->save($this->request->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Product updated'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Product could not be updated'));
    }else{
        $this->request->data = $product;
    }
}
}
```

The edit.ctp file

```
 <?php echo $this->element('Products/form'); ?>
```

They state in the book the header should look different between add.ctp and edit.ctp, but for the life of me I can't see the difference.

also in form.ctp it is missing the

```
?>
```

wanted to know if this was a typo...

Comment: In form.ctp did you used echo $this->Form->input('id');  ?

Comment: The missing ?> in ctp files sure is a typo.

Comment: the .input('id'); fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form should be like this

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Product',array('action' => 'edit'));
echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type'=>'hidden')); 
echo $this->Form->inputs();
echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));
?>
```

That's it.